# Storing EC2server images in bucket "subfolders"

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, amazon-ami

I am creating an AMI (Amazon EC2 server image) for all the servers I'm working on. Every server image is separated into some dozens of tar files:

```
Splitting /mnt/routing-4-server-Ubuntu-x86-64.tar.gz.enc...
Created routing-4-server-Ubuntu-x86-64.part.00
Created routing-4-server-Ubuntu-x86-64.part.01
Created routing-4-server-Ubuntu-x86-64.part.02
Created routing-4-server-Ubuntu-x86-64.part.03
Created routing-4-server-Ubuntu-x86-64.part.04
...
...
Created routing-4-server-Ubuntu-x86-64.part.48
Created routing-4-server-Ubuntu-x86-64.part.49
```

When I upload these files to a bucket called `my-servers-august-9`, I get a big mess of files. It will be a a problem when I want to delete some images.

I have tried to store them under subfolders, [but this concept seems not to be working in the S3 environment, and the explanations in the Amazon forums quite baffling](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/message.jspa?messageID=126806).

Any idea how can I create this folder structure?

```
my-servers-august-9
    routing server
        x86-64
            file
            file
            file
            ...
        i386
            file
            file
            file
            ...
     other-server1
        type
            files
        type
            files
     other-server2
        type
            files
```

Thanks,

Udi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

S3 doesn't support folders.  You can put a / in the filename to simulate folders, but they are really just objects in the bucket.

There are two ways to solve your problem.  You could either create a new bucket for each server (not recommended by Amazon, as you could quickly hit your 100 bucket limit), or you could use a structured naming scheme.

I personally use date-hostname-imagetype as my naming scheme.  In your case, you would probably want type-arch-date or something like that.

Then you can easily sort the list and delete the files you don't need.

Good luck!